# How can I prevent html content moving all over the screen at certain CSS breakpoints?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a mini-email application. I inserted some dummy emails into the HTML content and it looks all good on desktops and some mobile screens. On a screen size of 360px on mobile it looks good. If you go up to 380px using the chrome developer tools two HTML items move to the left. If you use the chrome developer tools and set it to responsive and try increasing the width of the screen, every element is static except these two elements which move around as you are increasing the size of the screen.

This is the HTML content

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .date-container {
    width: 260px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  }
  .calendar-container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 85%;
    top: 2px;
    transform: translateX(3px);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  }
  .calendar-container img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .calendar-container>div span {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  .date-container div:last-of-type img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: translate(230px, 11px);
  }
  .text-container {
    margin: 0 10px 0 15px;
  }
  .text-container h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .text-container h1>span {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding-right: 3px;
  }
  .email-table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .email-table table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
  }
  td,
  th {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .email-table table tr:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EEEDED;
  }
  th:first-of-type>span img {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    transform: translate(38px, -13px);
  }
  th:first-of-type {
    color: black;
  }
  th {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  .date {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .date>span img {
    display: none;
  }
  th:first-of-type:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #838383;
    width: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(56px, -25px);
  }
  th:nth-of-type(2):after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #838383;
    width: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(15px, 3px);
  }
  th:nth-of-type(3)::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #838383;
    width: 1.5px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(8px, 3px);
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 95px;
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)):after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #E1DEDE;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)) td:first-of-type {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)):before {
    content: url('../assets/icon_mail_sp.svg');
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(15px, 10px);
  }
  .email-table table tr td:last-of-type {
    transform: translateX(120px);
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(4)) td:last-of-type::after {
    content: url('../assets/icon_arrow02.svg');
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  .email-table table tr:nth-of-type(4) td:last-of-type span:last-of-type::after {
    content: url('../assets/icon_arrow02.svg');
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(6)~tr::after {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(6)~tr::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .second-data {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: -1;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  .third-data {
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: -1;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  td:last-of-type {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .first-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  .first-third-data {
    transform: translate(-20px, -27px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(2) td:first-of-type {
    transform: translate(20px, -2px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translate(20px, -15px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(3) {
    transform: translate(5px, -15px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'bbb.bbbb@example.com';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-85px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translate(20px, -15px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(4) td:first-of-type {
    transform: translate(20px, -3px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(4) td:nth-of-type(2) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2):after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'xxx@example.com, www.www@example.com';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-108px, 92px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(5) td:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'ddd.dddd@example.com';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-85px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(5) td:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .fourth-second-data .second-text span:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .fourth-second-data .second-text span:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'vvv.vvv@example.com, uuu@example.com, ...';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-155px, 15px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(6) td:first-of-type {
    transform: translate(20px);
  }
  .second-text span:last-of-type {
    transform: translate(40px, 15px);
    padding: 0 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .first-clip span:first-of-type img {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  .second-second-data {
    transform: translate( 27px, -20px);
  }
  .second-third-data {
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .third-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  .third-third-data {
    transform: translate(10px, -20px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .fourth-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  .fourth-third-data {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .fourth-third-data:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: '[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement';
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translate(-80px, -40px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .last-attachment span:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .last-attachment span:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'sss@example.com, rrr.rrrr@example.com, ...';
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translate(-140px, 5px);
  }
  .last-attachment span:last-of-type {
    transform: translate(50px, 2px);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0 3px;
  }
  .fifth-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  .fifth-third-data {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .fifth-third-data:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: '[HR-887(Revised: Office Expansion Project Tea...';
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translate(-120px, -15px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  tr td:last-of-type>span img {
    transform: translateX(60px);
    display: block;
  }
  .first-clip span:last-of-type>span img {
    transform: translateX(3px);
    display: block;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(7) td {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(8) td {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(9) td {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(10) td,
  tr:nth-of-type(10) td:last-of-type {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(11) td,
  tr:nth-of-type(11) td:last-of-type {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="email">
  <div class="date-container">
    <div class="calendar-container">
      <img src="./assets/icon_calender.svg" alt="">
      <div>
        <span>2019/12/31 - 2020/1/3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="./assets/icon_search.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container email">
    <h1>Results: <span>10</span>mail(s)</h1>
    <input class="search-email" type="text" placeholder="search">
  </div>
  <div class="email-table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>From <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th class="date">Date <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>aaa@example.com</td>
        <td class="second-data first-second-data">zzz.zzz@example.com</td>
        <td class="third-data first-third-data">[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement</td>
        <td>0:20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>bbb.bbbb@exam... </td>
        <td class="second-data second-second-data">yyy@example.com</td>
        <td class="third-data second-third-data">[web:333] "Web Contact"</td>
        <td>0:10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>ccc@example.com </td>
        <td class="second-data third-second-data">
          <div class="text-attachment">
            <span>xxx@example.com, ...</span>
            <span>+1</span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="third-data third-third-data">Happy New Year! Greetings for the New Year.</td>
        <td>
          <div class="attachment first-clip">
            <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
            <span>0:00</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>ddd.dddd@exam...</td>
        <td class="second-data fourth-second-data">
          <div class="text-attachment second-text">
            <span>vvv.vvv@example.com, ... </span>
            <span>+1</span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="third-data fourth-third-data">[HR-887(Revised: Office Expansion Project Team)] Notice of off... </td>
        <td>Jan 01</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>eee@example.com</td>
        <td class="second-data fifth-second-data">
          <div class="text-attachment last-attachment">
            <span>sss@example.com, .... </span>
            <span>+2</span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="third-data fifth-third-data">[Github] Logout page</td>
        <td>Jan 01</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>fff.ffff@example.c... </td>
        <td>qqq.qqq@example.com</td>
        <td>［dev］ Postfix 3.1.12 / 3.2.9 / 3.3.4 / 3.4.5</td>
        <td>Jan 01</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>ggg@example.com </td>
        <td>ppp@example.com</td>
        <td>Re: [Github] Brush-up on loading animation </td>
        <td>Jan 01</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>hhh.hhh@examp...</td>
        <td>ooo.ooo@example.com</td>
        <td>Workplace Summary for sample, Inc.: Jun 2 - Jun 9</td>
        <td>
          <div class="attachment">
            <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
            <span>Jan 01</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>iii@example.com</td>
        <td>nnn@example.com</td>
        <td>I love you</td>
        <td>
          <div class="attachment last-clip">
            <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
            <span>2019/12/31</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="email-body">
        <td>Pablo-Diego-...</td>
        <td>Pablo-Diego-José-Francisc...
        </td>
        <td>[info:888] ABC EQUIPMENT COMPANY</td>
        <td>2019/12/31</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

The elements are the first span in the div with the class of the second text and the table data directly after it. How can I make them static irresponsive of whatever the screen size is increased to.

This is the [JS fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ajs7p1rb/). Just reduce the width of the screen to see it

Comment: Try to put your code on https://jsfiddle.net/ and edit your question to include the link. Your requirement are not clear at all...

Comment: Will do this immediately.

Comment: I added the jsfiddle link

Comment: Your html and CSS code is OVERCOMPLICATED because of bad coding. You don't need to add a class to every single element on the page, you've to use CSS rules smartly). Said that, I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Please, could you explain better? Where do you want those elements to go when you insrease the width of the page?

Comment: If you decrease the width of the page, you would notice there are two elements that move relative to the width. The rest of the elements remain static. How can I get those elements to not move? when the width is increased or decreased. The other elements look good except those two.